# If a non-Muslim curses a Muslim, will the Muslim's life be in turmoil?

Tags: non-muslim, curse

If a non-Muslim curses a Muslim, will the Muslim's life be in turmoil?

I am the Muslim in the question. I don't have much knowledge about cursing in Islam. Only that our Prophet (PBUH) stayed away from cursing anybody or any sect.

Whenever something bad happens to me, my thoughts go back to the non-Muslim who cursed me. (It was because of a misunderstanding.)

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to take your time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: "Only that, our Prophet (PBUH) stayed away from cursing anybody or any sect." I thought him saying "may you never be able to" to a man who did not take his suggestion to eat with the right hand was considered a curse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly speaking, let’s illustrate it by presenting a related hadith (tradition). It is said Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his family) said (its approximate translation):

> Whenever curse gets out of the mouth of the person who curses, it
>   sees, if it find a way towards the mentioned thing, it goes towards
>   that, otherwise it will return to the individual who has cursed.

As much as I research, I didn’t find if a non-Muslim …, but it can be inferred from the hadith (and other hadiths) that the curse won’t reach/annoy the person who doesn’t deserve of that curse. It means: No curse would be effective against you if you have not done any bad thing to be deserved that.

---

Let’s present another related hadith from Imam Muhammad al-Baqir (a.s.) as the fifth Imam of Shia Islam, who said:

> Refrain from cursing Mo’men (believer), that it will come back to you
>   (yourselves)

And so forth.

---

**Source**:

[akhlagh.porsemani.ir](http://akhlagh.porsemani.ir/node/1148) (Farsi)

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa16492) (Arabic)